# Can I use my Nvidia graphics card in safe mode?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, safe-mode

Can I run in safe mode while using my graphics card?

I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 430, but when I run in safe mode, it uses my basic built-in graphics.

Is that normal?

Is it possible to run in safe mode and use the Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: Why are you running in safe mode? Maybe it would be better to fix the underlying problem?

Answer (score 4):

Source [In Windows, what is Safe Mode used for and why?](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question575.htm)

> Safe Mode is a special way for Windows to load when there is a system-critical problem that interferes with the normal operation of Windows. The purpose of Safe Mode is to allow you to troubleshoot Windows and try to determine what is causing it to not function correctly.

...

> **Instead of the normal graphics device driver, Safe Mode uses standard VGA graphics mode. This mode is supported by all Windows-compatible video cards**.

**Is it possible to run in safe mode while using the nvidia graphics card?**

The answer is maybe. This is because while the Nvidia **drivers** are not used, the card itself could still be used to display VGA output.

When the VGA driver is used the video BIOS will decide how to display the output.

Note: The motherboard built-in graphics can be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That's what I thought. I have a newly installed game that will not launch. It gives no error code or anything, just gives the wait icon, then nothing. I thought it might be my video card causing the problem. I've looked high and low and tried every fix I've found, but still no luck

Comment: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You wouldn't be using Nvidia *drivers*, but you'd still be able to use the *card*. (Whether it's actually doing so or not depends on if there's switchable graphics or other driver-based GPU-selection going on.)

Comment: Answer updated.